Querying Bitbucket Server from Morpheus script, file "could not be edited because it has been changed on the 'master' branch."
I have a Bitbucket server that contains a single file called values.yaml, with a bunch of branches that each branch off of the master branch and update the contents of that yaml file. I'm working on a script in a Morpheus-based platform that's supposed to send a query to the Bitbucket server API to update the contents of the file on an existing branch (using this query), but I'm running into an issue. I'm able to make several queries to Bitbucket to get the branch info, the most recent commit id, etc. and all of those go through successfully, but when I make the put request to update the file I get a 409 response with the error message "No change was committed: 'values.yaml' could not be edited because it has been changed on the 'master' branch".
I've confirmed that the master branch hasn't been changed in over a year and the branch I'm trying to update was created only a week ago. What's more, I was able to replicate this query in Postman and every time I send the query from Postman I get a 200 response and the file gets updated, but I still get a failure when I try and send the query from my script in Morpheus. Does this issue seem familiar to anyone? Does anyone know what this response from Bitbucket server indicates and why I might be getting it here?
